# How can we resolve DB2 java.io.CharConversionException during Spark submission

Tags: scala, apache-spark, db2

I am getting this below error during spark submit:

> org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][4.17.28] Caught java.io.CharConversionException.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
>           at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:731)

As per IBM documentation [Click here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1IC74895), I added this below property but till getting same error. I am using `db2jcc4.jar` driver.

> Is there any way to pass db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder during spark
>   submission.

```
System.setProperty("db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder", "3")    
val prop = new Properties()
prop.put("driver", driver)
prop.put("db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder", "3")
prop.put("-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder", "3")
prop.put("continueBatchOnError", "true")`

sqlContext.read.jdbc(
  url = url,
  table = table,
  predicates = parts,
  connectionProperties = prop)
```

Comment: You can also pass this property on the database connection string by appending after the database name the string `;charsetDecoderEncoder=3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have resolved DB2 java.io.CharConversionException  issue only passing two parameter to spark driver & executor.

```
--conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3' 
--conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3'
```